# Java looking in wrong directory for XML

Tags: java, slick

I found this suggestion on a Stack Exchange site to print out what the current directory is:

```
File file = new File(".");
for(String fileNames : file.list()) 
    System.out.println(fileNames);
```

Basically, when I run a game in Eclipse, I get this:

[image]

But when I compile the game and run it, it prints out this (it prints out the stuff that is in the same directory as the [JAR file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) is). Images, and sound are working fine. It's just the XML file that is causing this.

[image]

How do I make Java read XML files from res folder like it does for images and sound in Eclipse?

My particular code that loads the XML is at http://pastebin.com/59Nt7Dtd.

[Slick2D](http://www.slick2d.org/about/) documentation is at http://www.slick2d.org/javadoc/.

Comment: This question isn't really gamedev related. It would be better suited for stackoverflow

Comment: But im using Slick2d, the particle class is from slick2d example page  http://www.slick2d.org/wiki/index.php/Configurable_emitters_code_example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it works in Eclipse is because you are in the project root when you do this:

```
particleImage = new Image("res/particles/particle.png", false);
```

For consistency, put your XML file there as well or if you don't want to run it from Eclipse, but from a [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29), integrate an absolute data path in your code (do not hardcode it in your source files).

Comment: how do i get absolute data path from code, i want to load evreything from project room /res

Comment: @Matthew read the API documentation for the Java File class.

Comment: Ok so i made it absolute path but now this happends : http://shrani.si/f/2H/13W/131vAM3/error3.png    ,  so my question is shouldnt the absolute path have filename inluded, the name of the file was 5.jar but it was not shown in the absolute path

Comment: The absolute path is composed out of: DirPath + RelativePath + Filename. If you are trying to get the jar, your dirPath should be something like C:\Project\Particles and your relativePath \res (\bin) and the filaname a.xml (b.jar). Hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Shouldnt the path be something like this for this case D:\PathToJar\game.jar\res\particles\particleXmlFile.xml    ,  because the particlexml file is inside the game.jar

Comment: Oh you want to access it from within the jar, yes that is correct , sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: So do i manipulate the string and add the filename at the middle ? But if someone then changes the name of jar the particles wont work.

Comment: Then you would have to get the dirpath for the current jar file regardless of its name. Don't know if that possible tho.

Comment: path =(Particle.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()+path);  , with this i get the full path but still error : http://shrani.si/f/2C/10S/X3a1h7c/error4.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8578/discussion-between-cristina-and-matthew)

Answer (score 0):

```
 path="/res/particles/file.xml";
 emitter = ParticleIO.loadEmitter(path);
```

This fixed the problem thanks to Cristina